# is it possible to take the statistics for extracted region using R?

Tags: r

I have a binary file with size of (360 720 )for the globe.I wrote the code given below to read and extract an area from that file.  when I use summary for the whole file I got.

```
summary(a, na.rm=FALSE)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
0.00    1.00    3.00    4.15    7.00   20.00  200083 .
```

But when used summary for the region(b) which I extracted, I got many V1,V2. Which is not right I should have got one line (as for a)not many V1,V2.

Here is the code:

```
X <- c(200:300)
Y <- c(150:190)
conne <- file("C:\\initial-WTD.bin", "rb")
a=readBin(conne, numeric(), size=4,  n=360*720, signed=TRUE)
a[a == -9999] <- NA
y <- matrix(data=a,ncol=360,nrow=720)
image(t(t(y[X,Y])),ylim=c(1,0))
b = y[X,Y]
summary(b,na.rm=FALSE)

   V1            V2            V3            V4            V5           V6            V7       
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA   Min.   : 8   Min.   : NA   Min.   :   
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:11   1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.:  
 Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median : NA   Median :14   Median : NA   Median  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN   Mean   :14   Mean   :NaN   Mean     
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.:17   3rd Qu.: NA   3rd  
  Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA   Max.   :20   Max.   : NA   Max.     
 NA's   :101   NA's   :101   NA's   :101   NA's   :101   NA's   :99   NA's   :101   NA's   :
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your indexing of a matrix, but some place prior to accessing it:

```
a <- matrix(1:100, 10, 10)
summary( a[1:3,1:3] )
       V1            V2             V3      
 Min.   :1.0   Min.   :11.0   Min.   :21.0  
 1st Qu.:1.5   1st Qu.:11.5   1st Qu.:21.5  
 Median :2.0   Median :12.0   Median :22.0  
 Mean   :2.0   Mean   :12.0   Mean   :22.0  
 3rd Qu.:2.5   3rd Qu.:12.5   3rd Qu.:22.5  
 Max.   :3.0   Max.   :13.0   Max.   :23.0
```

You managed to hit a few non-NA values (apparently only 2) but why are you doing this with such sparse data? I scaled this up to 100 columns (out of 1000) and still got the expected results.

Comment: My problem is why I am getting V1 , v2 , v3 ....Why for the whole file ,it was only one v1. while for the extracted region I got v1, V2 V3...........there is no problem with NA.

Comment: Your 'a' object is apparently not a matrix. You need to use str() to see what it really is.

Comment: Yes it is not matrix,but I assigned it to y and y is now matrix

Comment: So you need to explain your problem. You were asking why you were getting multiple columns in the summary output. That should now be clear.